# Why does python keep saying the return statement is outside of the function?

Tags: python, return

```
single_char = {}
for item in lines:
    for index in range(len(item)):
        if item[index - 1] in space:
            if item[index + 1] in space:
                if item[index] in alplist:
                    char = item[index]
                    single_char[char] = index
                    return single_char
                else:
                    continue
            else:
                continue
        else:
            continue​
```

This is my function by for some reason Python keeps telling me that the return statement "return single_char" is outside of the function. Can somebody please explain how i can fix this problem.

Comment: Because you screwed up your indentation.

Comment: Well, there is no function definition as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

There is no function. And **return statement should be always inside a function.**
Use `def` keyword to define a function in python.

**Example:**

---

```
def sum(a, b):
    return a+b
```